# Make Progressbar circle go away after GPS coordinates set

Tags: android, multithreading

How can i make the Progressbar circle go away after GPS coordinates returned by my other class that does the work?

based on my current code, it never goes away even after GPS stuff is set.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mNet.locationSourceEnabled()) {
        if (mNet.mLat == 0.0) {
            pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    Runnable runThis = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            if (mNet.locationSourceEnabled()) {
                mNet.getLocation();
            }
            Looper.loop();
        }
    };
```

And if I add "pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);" after "Looper.loop();", then it never shows up! any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the progress bar's visibility to INVISIBLE or GONE when the GPS is set.  If the other class doesn't have access to the progress bar, then have it call a callback function on an interface which is registered with that class.

Comment: the other class doesnt have access to progressbar circle. so i have to make it visible in the main UI (as above code) and call the method of the other class to start looking for GPS (getLocation). so far so good, but how can i make it wait until GPS is set and then set progressbar's visibility to GONE?